# Fields $F < K <L$ where $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ not a quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/F$ be a finite Galois extension. When $K$ is a normal intermediate subfield, $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is the quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$ by $\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$. At first I thought that when $K$ was not normal, $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is the quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$ by the normal closure of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$. But actually, that quotient is $\operatorname{Aut}(K'/F)$, where $K'$ is the largest normal subfield of $L$ contained in $K$.

So for example, if $L$ is the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ by the normal closure of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}))$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q})$.

(Correct me if I'm wrong about any of this.)

**Question:** Can someone give me a good example of a case where $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is **no** quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$? The case above doesn't quite work, because $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ is a quotient of $D_8 \cong \operatorname{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, if $K/F$ is Galois then its Galois groups is the quotient, this is a standard result of Galois theory. If it is not Galois, then I suppose one can still define the automorphism group, but it is of little significance.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus There was an important "not" missing from the question.

Comment: What I'm looking for (mostly as a matter of curiosity) is an example where $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$ are such that it becomes obvious that the quotienting doesn't work, because $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is not a quotient of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}$Let $F = \Q$, and take $L$ to be the splitting field of a suitable polynomial $f \in \Q[x]$ of degree $5$, such that $\Aut(L/F) \cong S_{5}$. (For instance, $f = x^{5} − 6 x + 3$ will work.)

Let $K$ be the field generated by three of the roots of $f$, say $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$. This has degree at most (actually equal to, I believe) $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$ over $F$, so $K \subsetneq L$, and $\Aut(K/F)$ has order at most $\Size{K : F} \le 60$.

Now $\Aut(K/F)$ has order divisible by $3$, as it will contain a $3$-cycle  from $S_{5}$ that permutes the three roots $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$. But $S_{5} \cong \Aut(L/F)$ has no proper quotient of order divisible by $3$.